# Couchbase: How to delete item from list based on child value?

Tags: nosql, couchbase

Couchbase 2.5+

New to couchbase here. I'm looking to delete an item from a list where one of the child items of it based on the value of the child items. For example if I wanted to delete all records in the list `scores` where the child `score < 0.2`

This item has a key of `"dim::100020891::2020-10-04"`

I thought of running this, but it's not working

```
UPDATE Q1036628 USE KEYS "dim::100020891::2020-10-04" SET scores=ARRAY_REMOVE(scores, {
      "score"< "0.2"
    })
```

Couchbase item:

```
   [
          {
            "Q1036628": {
              "record_update_dt": "2020-10-04",
              "scores": [
                {
                  "name": "A",
                  "score": 0.01
                },
                {
                  "name": "B",
                  "score": 0.5
                },
                {
                  "name": "C",
                  "score": 0.26
                },
                {
                  "name": "D",
                  "score": 0.17
                }
              ],
              "id": "100020891"
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: A little confused: you say "Couchbase 2.5", but you are referencing N1QL, which wasn't in Couchbase until 4.x. Which version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: Also, your "Couchbase item" looks to be an array. Is it truly a document with an array (uncommon but possible), or is there a Q1036628 bucket containing a document with key "100020891"?

Comment: good questions. I made a mistake on the Couchbase version. We're using couchbase 5.5. Q1036628 is the bucket with an item that looks like the above. Each id will have several attributes and we're debating the best model to create this as (put the attributes all in a list or put the attributes each in their own document). Right now all of the attributes are in one document and the will be updated individually later on.We aren't married to the idea though.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ARRAY clause.

```
UPDATE Q1036628 USE KEYS "dim::100020891::2020-10-04" 
SET scores = ARRAY s FOR s IN scores WHEN s.score >= 0.2 END
```

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#array

You might need to play around with the syntax a bit; I don't have an instance handy.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more addition to Johan Larson solution.

WHERE clause controls what documents to mutate. SET clause controls what to update. You have condition in the SET clause. If there is NO objects in scores array has score < 0.2 still mutates (i.e it updates same value). To avoid that you need to have WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE Q1036628 AS d USE KEYS "dim::100020891::2020-10-04" 
SET d.scores = ARRAY s FOR s IN d.scores WHEN s.score >= 0.2 END
WHERE ANY s IN d.scores SATISFIES s.score < 0.2 END;
```